# Is there any method to "spread" only the Synthetic events passed in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to get only the synthetic events and insert them in my DOM element. The reason for this is to prevent manually inserting the synthetic events one by one. Some may say spread the props `{..props}` into the DOM element but the problem is that DOM elements may not recognize other props as they are not valid HTML attributes. Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pull out the other props first? `const {some, component, props, ...rest} = props; ... <div {...rest}>`. Or write a helper function that takes in `props` and returns a new object that only contains "known" event handler props. If all that doesn't help, please provide more information, ideally with an example.

Comment: Yes that makes sense but the maintenance will be the problem here, if you have any props that will be added to the component in the future, you must also exclude them from the `...rest` props. I know your recommendation is a small effort but in my opinion, it is much cleaner and efficient to have a synthetic events spreading method. Like for example `...props._events`.

Comment: Then you would have to bring this up with React team.

Comment: yes, I will. but for the meantime, I think I'll just stick to your implementation. But if you guys have any other suggestions, feel free to post so that others can get an idea. Thanks and happy coding.